# Windows 8 Calendar repeatable tasks

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-calendar-app

Is it possible to specify the end of repeatable event in Windows 8 calendar? Eg. I create an event that takes place 'every week' starting from 30.10.12. As far as I'm concerned it is being repeated till the end of calendar. 
Now I use Google calendar synchronization to deal with it. Is there any other solution for that ?

Answer (score 4):

Taken from [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_cp-winapps/calendar-app-repeating-event/37c7132a-b8d5-49d6-a728-61c91f0dab12): Use [Hotmail Calendar](https://calendar.live.com/) on the web. When the calendar syncs to Windows 8, you'll have your desired effect.  Then just do a sync to your Google calendar.

Comment: Yes, it can be a solution, but I supposed that such thing can be done using win8 components only.

Comment: Yea, there really isn't any reason why it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

This app has Calendar and Tasks http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/app/winpim-calendar/08436f52-dded-44a5-9508-c2b22235ac1d

Comment: Could you add some more information about this? Screenshot or just some more specifics would make this answer much more useful and able to stand on its own.